# please check on this xpath that does not work in my android

Tags: java, android, xpath

I use eclipse and I want to pick out node mytag text. What should I do to get it? I have the following code:

```
           XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            String expression = "/outertag/innertag/mytag/text()";
            InputSource inputSource = new InputSource("http://www.anddev.org/images/tut/basic/parsingxml/example.xml");
            NodeList nodes = null;
            try {
                nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(expression, inputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            int i=nodes.getLength();
```

The materials I referred is http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp
Now when I check in debug, it gives nodes content very complicated, but none of them is  mytag text -- anddev.org rulez  In order to take this out, what should I do?
Thanks!

The xml file in that website(parameter of URL):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<outertag>
    <innertag sampleattribute="innertagAttribute">
        <mytag>
            anddev.org rulez =)
        </mytag>
        <tagwithnumber thenumber="1337"/>
    </innertag>
</outertag>
```

in result i is 1. But the nodes does not give any text string. It's a list of "description" starting with m. All I want, is to take that text out. Because what I really need to parse, is a internal website, that is a huge table. And I need to store data from that table according to their each category. For example, one file contains name and math score, the other contains name and physics.

```
<TABLE border="2" frame="hsides" rules="groups"
          summary="Code page support in different versions
                   of MS Windows.">
<CAPTION>CODE-PAGE SUPPORT IN MICROSOFT WINDOWS</CAPTION>
<COLGROUP align="center">
<COLGROUP align="left">
<COLGROUP align="center" span="2">
<COLGROUP align="center" span="3">
<THEAD valign="top">
<TR>
<TH>Code-Page<BR>ID
<TH>Name
<TH>ACP
<TH>OEMCP
<TH>Windows<BR>NT 3.1
<TH>Windows<BR>NT 3.51
<TH>Windows<BR>95
<TBODY>
<TR><TD>1200<TD>Unicode (BMP of ISO/IEC-10646)<TD><TD><TD>X<TD>X<TD>*
<TR><TD>1250<TD>Windows 3.1 Eastern European<TD>X<TD><TD>X<TD>X<TD>X
<TR><TD>1251<TD>Windows 3.1 Cyrillic<TD>X<TD><TD>X<TD>X<TD>X
<TR><TD>1252<TD>Windows 3.1 US (ANSI)<TD>X<TD><TD>X<TD>X<TD>X
<TR><TD>1253<TD>Windows 3.1 Greek<TD>X<TD><TD>X<TD>X<TD>X
<TR><TD>1254<TD>Windows 3.1 Turkish<TD>X<TD><TD>X<TD>X<TD>X
<TR><TD>1255<TD>Hebrew<TD>X<TD><TD><TD><TD>X
<TR><TD>1256<TD>Arabic<TD>X<TD><TD><TD><TD>X
<TR><TD>1257<TD>Baltic<TD>X<TD><TD><TD><TD>X
<TR><TD>1361<TD>Korean (Johab)<TD>X<TD><TD><TD>**<TD>X
<TBODY>
<TR><TD>437<TD>MS-DOS United States<TD><TD>X<TD>X<TD>X<TD>X
<TR><TD>708<TD>Arabic (ASMO 708)<TD><TD>X<TD><TD><TD>X
<TR><TD>709<TD>Arabic (ASMO 449+, BCON V4)<TD><TD>X<TD><TD><TD>X
<TR><TD>710<TD>Arabic (Transparent Arabic)<TD><TD>X<TD><TD><TD>X
<TR><TD>720<TD>Arabic (Transparent ASMO)<TD><TD>X<TD><TD><TD>X
</TABLE>
```

Everything after and  , so it has to be nodeList I think.

Comment: you should post a sample of your xml

Comment: The sample is given in the code, the parameter of InputSource

Comment: Is it a very big file? You can always paste a snippet of the markup here if it's too large.

Comment: Please tell us exactly which result you get from your code. All you have shown is `int i=nodes.getLength();`, with the sample you have mentioned in the code (`http://www.anddev.org/images/tut/basic/parsingxml/example.xml`) and the path `/outertag/innertag/mytag/text()` I would expect `i` to have the value `1`. Do you get a different value? And where and how are you trying to read out the contents of the returned node(s)?

Comment: Hei, I have changed the post.

Answer (score 0):

`evaluate`

can return different objects, because your XPath can return different parts of the document that will need to be represented as different objects. The version of evaluate you are calling, returns a NodeList which is probably overkill if you know you're going to be getting text (which your XPath suggests you do).

Instead you could call the simpler:

```
String evaluate(java.lang.String expression, InputSource source)
```

E.G:

```
String myTagText = "";
try {
    myTagText = xpath.evaluate(expression, inputSource);
} catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(myTagText);
```

Comment: Hei, this really works if it has only one node. But actually it is a table, and it has multiple <TR>, I must take all of them out, and check that "myTagText". Because the real xml website is an internal students score table, some item is empty, cannot know how it looks like in advance. But hei, thanks for trying to help

Comment: In which case your XPath will need changing. Currently it gets the text from myTag (which works with the sample XML you've included above), but you're saying in the *real* XML it's not text within myTag but more nodes. Can you give a sample of the actual XML you want to parse?

Comment: Hei, I modified the question post with an XML table example for easier reading, I need to filter out everything after <TH> and <TD> to find out the title(in <TH>), and student name and score(in <TD>). Thank you for help.